# How to Get A Count From Another Table In SQL? PART 2

Tags: sql, count, inner-join, outer-join

Well I have already got my quesiton answered in this post...

[How to Get A Count From Another Table In SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939989/how-to-get-a-count-from-another-table-in-sql)

However, now I have another question...

In the end I used this query

```
SELECT 
  Mensajes.IdMensaje, 
  Mensajes.IdCliente, 
  Mensajes.CorreoCliente, 
  Mensajes.CorreosAdicionales, 
  Mensajes.Tema, 
  Mensajes.Mensaje, 
  Mensajes.Fecha, 
  Mensajes.Hora, 
  COUNT(Archivos.IdArchivo) AS Archivos 
FROM Mensajes 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Archivos ON Mensajes.IdMensaje = Archivos.IdMensaje 
GROUP BY 
  Mensajes.IdMensaje, 
  Mensajes.IdCliente, 
  Mensajes.CorreoCliente, 
  Mensajes.CorreosAdicionales, 
  Mensajes.Tema, 
  Mensajes.Mensaje, 
  Mensajes.Fecha, 
  Mensajes.Hora 
ORDER BY Mensajes.Fecha DESC, Mensajes.Hora DESC
```

in the last post I mentioned that there was a table called Clientes, and now I want to add this to the previous query (on the select)

```
(Clientes.ApellidoPaterno + ' ' + 
 Clientes.ApellidoMaterno + ' ' + 
 Clientes.Nombre) AS Cliente
```

I have tried using INNER, RIGHT OUTER and LEFT OUTER JOIN, and none of those work...

I want to display all data that the precious query displays, but I want to add another column that displays the Client's Full Name...

Clientes has a FK with Mensajes on Clientes.IdCliente = Mensajes.IdCliente...

Hope you can help me
Thanks

Comment: Just join `Clientes` ON `Mensajes.IdCliente`, and add the concatenated string to the `GROUP BY` section?  Also, the title to your question doesn't really reflect your current issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
SELECT  M.IdMensaje, M.IdCliente, M.CorreoCliente, M.CorreosAdicionales, 
        M.Tema, M.Mensaje, M.Fecha, M.Hora, 
        COALESCE(C.ApellidoPaterno,'') + ' ' + COALESCE(C.ApellidoMaterno,'') + ' ' + COALESCE(C.Nombre,'') Cliente,
        COUNT(A.IdArchivo) AS Archivos
FROM Mensajes M
LEFT JOIN Archivos A
    ON M.IdMensaje = A.IdMensaje 
LEFT JOIN Clientes C
    ON C.IdCliente = N.IdCliente
GROUP BY M.IdMensaje, M.IdCliente, M.CorreoCliente, M.CorreosAdicionales, 
         M.Tema, M.Mensaje, M.Fecha, M.Hora, 
         COALESCE(C.ApellidoPaterno,'') + ' ' + COALESCE(C.ApellidoMaterno,'') + ' ' + COALESCE(C.Nombre,'')
ORDER BY M.Fecha DESC, M.Hora DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `JOIN` to the table and then add the field to the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
  Mensajes.IdMensaje, 
  Mensajes.IdCliente, 
  Mensajes.CorreoCliente, 
  Mensajes.CorreosAdicionales, 
  Mensajes.Tema, 
  Mensajes.Mensaje, 
  Mensajes.Fecha, 
  Mensajes.Hora, 
  COUNT(Archivos.IdArchivo) AS Archivos,
  c.Cliente
FROM Mensajes 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Archivos 
    ON Mensajes.IdMensaje = Archivos.IdMensaje 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT IdCliente, (ApellidoPaterno + ' ' + ApellidoMaterno + ' ' + Nombre) Cliente
    FROM Clientes
) c
    on Mensajes.IdCliente = Clientes.IdCliente
GROUP BY 
  Mensajes.IdMensaje, 
  Mensajes.IdCliente, 
  Mensajes.CorreoCliente, 
  Mensajes.CorreosAdicionales, 
  Mensajes.Tema, 
  Mensajes.Mensaje, 
  Mensajes.Fecha, 
  Mensajes.Hora,
  c.Cliente
ORDER BY Mensajes.Fecha DESC, Mensajes.Hora DESC
```

Comment: You are missing `IdCliente` on the `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like:

```
SELECT
 Clientes.ApellidoPaterno + ' ' + Clientes.ApellidoMaterno + ' ' + Clientes.NombreCliente,
 Mensajes.*
FROM (
SELECT 
  Mensajes.IdMensaje, 
  Mensajes.IdCliente, 
  Mensajes.CorreoCliente, 
  Mensajes.CorreosAdicionales, 
  Mensajes.Tema, 
  Mensajes.Mensaje, 
  Mensajes.Fecha, 
  Mensajes.Hora, 
  COUNT(Archivos.IdArchivo) AS Archivos 
FROM Mensajes 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Archivos ON Mensajes.IdMensaje = Archivos.IdMensaje 
GROUP BY 
  Mensajes.IdMensaje, 
  Mensajes.IdCliente, 
  Mensajes.CorreoCliente, 
  Mensajes.CorreosAdicionales, 
  Mensajes.Tema, 
  Mensajes.Mensaje, 
  Mensajes.Fecha, 
  Mensajes.Hora 
) AS Mensajes
LEFT JOIN
  Clientes
ON
  Clientes.IdCliente = Mensajes.IdCliente
ORDER BY Mensajes.Fecha DESC, Mensajes.Hora DESC
```

Watch out on possible misspelling.

I used your query from question as subquery LEFT JOINED (to make sure that all records from subquery will stay after JOIN) with `Clientes` table.